# html align column right

Tags: css, html, html-table

I have this Html code :

```
  <tr>

    <td>
      <a type="text" 
        name="color" >@client.Login</a>
    </td>

    <td>
      <a type="text" 
        name="color" >@client.Mail</a>
    </td>
      <td>
      <a type="text" 
        name="color" >@client.Password</a>
    </td>
      <td>
      <a type="text" 
        name="color" >@client.Name</a>
    </td>
               <td width=10px align="left">
            @if (i == 0)
            {

      <input type="radio" 
        name="color" checked >
            }
            else
            {<input type="radio"  name="color" >
            }      
    </td>
  </tr>
```

My problem is in the radio button : it is so far to the other elements. the attribute `align` is obsolete in HTML5 .
[image: far]

the dimensions :
[image: dim]

So how can modify this snippet to got a good result?

Comment: use a stylesheet or inline style - `style="text-align:right;"`

Comment: sorry, change the right for left

Comment: Yes i changed , but the same result, i add another picture to my question

Comment: ah you have styled your checkbox, don't give it a width

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30318/discussion-between-lamloumi-and-pete)

Comment: You have some styles applied to you table that is controlling the table cell widths and so on.  Please post the relevant part of the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `text-align` instead of `align`:

```
<td width=10px style="text-align: right;">
    @if (i == 0)
    {
         <input type="radio" name="color" checked >
    } else{
        <input type="radio"  name="color" >
    }      
</td>
```

Comment: Why would this help (CSS `text-align` has the same effect as HTML `align`), and why was the answer accepted?